# Глобальная переменная GET

Tags: php, http

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с глобальной переменной GET.

На странице index.php есть список песен. Рядом с каждой песней есть ссылка на скачивание.
Когда я перехожу по ссылке, я попадаю на шаблон, в котором будет название песни, группа, картинка и т.д. которые берутся из переменной, а в строку должно добавляться "сайт.ру/shablon.php?группа-песня" вместо "сайт.ру/index.php". Вот. Но "сайт.ру/shablon.php?группа-песня" не отображается. Отображается только "сайт.ру/shablon.php?". Что я делаю не так?

```
//index.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
Группа1 - Песня1 <a href="shablon.php<? echo "?" . $SongID["a1"]; ?>">Скачать</a><br>
Группа2 - Песня2 <a href="shablon.php<? echo "?" . $SongID["a2"]; ?>">Скачать</a><br>
Группа3 - Песня3 <a href="shablon.php<? echo "?" . $SongID["a3"]; ?>">Скачать</a><br>

<?php
// Делаю многомерные массивы в которых хранятся песни
$SongID["a1"] = "Группа1-Песня1";
$SongID["a2"] = "Группа2-Песня2";
$SongID["a3"] = "Группа3-Песня3";
?>
</body>
</html>

//shablon.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
Группа1 - Песня1<br>
Группа2 - Песня2<br>
Группа3 - Песня3<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Почему массив с песнями объявляете уже после использования?
   Т.е. при создании ссылки массива еще нет, заполнять после "?" нечем. Попробуйте перенести инициализацию массива выше создания ссылок.
2. Почему передачу через $_GET производите как `"?песня"`? Я че-то думал, что надо так: `"?name=песня"`, т.е. надо переделать строчки:

   `Группа1 - Песня1 <a href="shablon.php?name=<? echo $SongID['a1']; ?>">Скачать</a><br>`
3. Вы используете глобальные переменные что ли? Я уж даже забыл как ими пользоваться, но че-то кажется, что в шаблоне выводится только

   Скачать `<a href="files/a1.rar"></a>`

Раз передаете параметр, то почему бы его не использовать?

```
Скачать `<a href="files/a1.rar"><?php echo $_REQUEST['name']; ?></a>`
```

$_REQUEST использовал, чтобы можно было параметры передавать не только GET`ом, но и POST`ом.

Comment: 1. Перенес массивы выше ссылок и все заработало.

2. Не хочу я в строчки лишнее добавлять, (я про "name").

3. Выводится. Потом наполню страницу.

4. То есть, в моем случае должно быть $_REQUEST['a1'] вместо $SongID["a1"]?

Comment: в вашем случае это будет $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]   
откуда сервер знает, что это именно a1??? поэтому и предложили вам ипользвать name или нечто подобное

Comment: @gm-111, можно и не добавлять, если настроить RewriteRule в .htaccess, т.е. он автоматически будет приводить к нужному виду (т.е. к ?name=songName), но при этом для пользователя будет отображаться, например, как server.com/index.php/songName (либо, что лучше, server.com/download/songName - главное правильно параметры обработать)

Comment: О, а так мне больше нравится. Но слишком сложно для меня, так как я учусь еще. Но возьму на заметку, спасибо.